# maven install fail

Tags: maven, playn

I follow the guide of how to use PlayN with Maven, but when i perform the command:

```
    maven install
```

it fails.

The error log is the following:

```
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-android-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-2:dex (default-dex) @ playn-showcase-android ---
    [INFO] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java [-Xmx1024m, -jar, /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar, --dex, --output=/home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/target/classes.dex, /home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/target/android-classes]
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ playn-showcase-android ---
    [INFO] Building jar: /home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/target/playn-showcase-android-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-android-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-2:apk (default-apk) @ playn-showcase-android ---
    [INFO] /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/aapt [package, -f, -M, /home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/res, --auto-add-overlay, -I, /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-11/android.jar, -F, /home/hox/Projects/playn/playn/sample/showcase/android/target/playn-showcase-android-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ap_]
    [ERROR] Cannot create the APKBuilder object
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkBuilder.(ApkBuilder.java:195)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.doAPKWithAPKBuilder(ApkMojo.java:334)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.createApkFile(ApkMojo.java:249)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase09package.ApkMojo.execute(ApkMojo.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] PlayN Project ..................................... SUCCESS [0.125s]
    [INFO] PlayN Project Archetype ........................... SUCCESS [0.650s]
    [INFO] PlayN Core ........................................ SUCCESS [1.962s]
    [INFO] PlayN JBox2D ...................................... SUCCESS [2.125s]
    [INFO] PlayN WebGL ....................................... SUCCESS [0.914s]
    [INFO] PlayN Java ........................................ SUCCESS [1.740s]
    [INFO] PlayN HTML ........................................ SUCCESS [1.419s]
    [INFO] PlayN Flash ....................................... SUCCESS [1.414s]
    [INFO] PlayN Android ..................................... SUCCESS [1.552s]
    [INFO] PlayN Server ...................................... SUCCESS [0.524s]
    [INFO] PlayN Demos Project ............................... SUCCESS [0.002s]
    [INFO] PlayN Hello Metaproject ........................... SUCCESS [0.003s]
    [INFO] PlayN Hello Core .................................. SUCCESS [0.574s]
    [INFO] PlayN Hello HTML .................................. SUCCESS [18.829s]
    [INFO] PlayN Hello Flash ................................. SUCCESS [22.045s]
    [INFO] PlayN Hello Android ............................... SUCCESS [14.519s]
    [INFO] PlayN Showcase Metaproject ........................ SUCCESS [0.003s]
    [INFO] PlayN Showcase Core ............................... SUCCESS [1.567s]
    [INFO] PlayN Showcase HTML ............................... SUCCESS [21.663s]
    [INFO] PlayN Showcase Flash .............................. SUCCESS [35.783s]
    [INFO] PlayN Showcase Android ............................ FAILURE [11.533s]
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Metaproject ............................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Core ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Cute HTML ................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Flash .................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Cute Android ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Payments .................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Payments Core ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Payments Demo Metaproject ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Payments Demo Core .......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN payments HTML ............................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN payments Server ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Payments Demo HTML .......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Tests Metaproject ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Benchmark Metaproject ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Benchmarks Core ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Benchmark HTML .............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Manual Tests Metaproject .................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Manual Tests Core ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Manual Tests HTML ........................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] PlayN Manual Tests Flash .......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2:20.302s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 25 15:44:44 CEST 2011
    [INFO] Final Memory: 122M/318M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:3.0.0-alpha-2:apk (default-apk) on project playn-showcase-android: Cannot create the APKBuilder object: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :playn-showcase-android
```

I found the same error [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/185473), but no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the recently released r14 of the Android SDK? It seems like it has some issues with the version of the Maven Android plugin playn uses. Try replacing the plugins section in `samples/showcase/android/pom.xml` with the following:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
      <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
      <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
      <sdk>
        <platform>11</platform>
      </sdk>
      <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
      <jvmArguments>
        <jvmArgument>-Xmx1024m</jvmArgument>
      </jvmArguments>
      <dex>
        <jvmArguments>
          <jvmArgument>-Xmx1024m</jvmArgument>
        </jvmArguments>
      </dex>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Then cd into samples/showcase and run mvn clean then mvn install.

If that works, I'll look at upgrading all the samples to use the latest android maven plugin later today.

Comment: It works! I made the same change to the cute sample and now _mvn install_ works. Thank you

Comment: Great! I just updated the repo to use the new version, so you should be able to pull and it'll all build.

Comment: The problem seems to persist with ADT rel15. Your solution worked. +1